# Mapping a compounded array from objects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simngle array of multiple values obtained from an input array of objects. Ideally I'd like to use "ES5" features to do this.

I need to transform an object such as this:

```
{
  image: "bat",
  count: 5
}
```

into this array `[bat, bat, bat, bat, bat]`

I think the code is the fastest way to explain:

```js
//game object state
var gameObj = {
objects: [
  {
    image: "bat",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    image: "spider",
    count: 4
  },
  {
    image: "frankie",
    count: 3
  }
],
imagesArr: [],
}

function gameObjectArrayBuilder(obj) {
  var resultArr = [];
  resultArr = obj.map(buildArr);

  function buildArr(prop) {
    var image = prop.image;
    var count = prop.count;
    while (prop.count > 0) {
      prop.count--
      return prop.image
    }
  }
  return resultArr;

}

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObjectArrayBuilder(gameObj.objects);

//View result
var html = document.querySelector("#content");
html.innerHTML = gameObj.imagesArr;
console.log(gameObj.imagesArr)

//Result should be
//[bat, bat, bat, bat, bat, spider, spider, spider, spider, frankie, frankie, frankie]
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: You're always returning on the first iteration in `while`

Comment: Better answer: `const arr = gameObj.objects.flatMap(e => Array(e.count).fill(e.image));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `new Array` and the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method for your case:

```js
var gameObj = {
  objects: [{
      image: "bat",
      count: 5
    },
    {
      image: "spider",
      count: 4
    },
    {
      image: "frankie",
      count: 3
    }
  ],
  imagesArr: [],
};

function repeatImages(acc, item, idx) {

  if (!(acc instanceof Array)) {
    acc = [];
  }

  return acc.concat(new Array(item.count).fill(item.image));

}

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObj.objects.reduce(repeatImages, []);

console.log(gameObj.imagesArr);
```

Comment: You also have to provide a polyfill for `fill` since the OP's using ES5.

Comment: Why are you checking if `acc instanceof Array` (and setting to an empty array) inside of the reduce iteration?

Answer (score 3):

To obtain an array of duplicate string values (ie "bat"), where the length of the array corresponds to a supplied variable (ie "obj.count"), you could do the following:

```js
const obj = { image: "bat", count: 5 };

const arr = Array.from({ length : obj.count }, () => (obj.image));

console.log(arr);
```

You could then build upon this to populate an array based on multiple input objects like this:

```js
var gameObj = {
  objects: [{
      image: "bat",
      count: 5
    },
    {
      image: "spider",
      count: 4
    },
    {
      image: "frankie",
      count: 3
    }
  ],
  imagesArr: [],
}

// Use reduce to obtain compounded array from all input objects
gameObj.imagesArr = gameObj.objects.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  // Concat acc array with resulting array from current obj
  return acc.concat(Array.from({ length: obj.count }, () => (obj.image)))

}, []);


console.log(gameObj.imagesArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution  For your example**

```js
//game object state
var gameObj = {
objects: [
  {
    image: "bat",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    image: "spider",
    count: 4
  },
  {
    image: "frankie",
    count: 3
  }
],
imagesArr: [],
}

function gameObjectArrayBuilder(obj) {
  var resultArr = [];
  obj.forEach((ele)=>{resultArr.push(...buildArr(ele))});

  function buildArr(prop) {
    var image = prop.image;
    var count = prop.count;
    var temp = []
    while (prop.count > 0) {
      prop.count--
      temp.push(prop.image)
    }
    return temp
  }
  return resultArr;

}

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObjectArrayBuilder(gameObj.objects);


//View result
var html = document.querySelector("#content");
html.innerHTML = gameObj.imagesArr;
console.log(gameObj.imagesArr)

//Result should be
//[bat, bat, bat, bat, bat, spider, spider, spider, spider, frankie, frankie, frankie]
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take the count and loop this count as long as it has a truthy value.

Instead of mapping ([`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)), I would reduce ([`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) the array, because the result set is an array with a count of items. In new user agents, [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) would work, but here an accumulator is necessary for getting all same items.

```js
function gameObjectArrayBuilder(array) {
    function buildArr(accumulator, object) {
        var count = object.count;
        while (count--) accumulator.push(object.image);
        return accumulator;
    }
  
    return array.reduce(buildArr, []);
}

var gameObj = { objects: [{ image: "bat", count: 5 }, { image: "spider", count: 4 }, { image: "frankie", count: 3 }], imagesArr: [] };

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObjectArrayBuilder(gameObj.objects);

var html = document.querySelector("#content");
html.innerHTML = gameObj.imagesArr;
console.log(gameObj.imagesArr)
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got it working with your solutions. Will come back to this thread to understand map, reduce, filter and while loops better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap` to produce the same result with less number of codes.

```js
//game object state
var gameObj = {
objects: [
  {
    image: "bat",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    image: "spider",
    count: 4
  },
  {
    image: "frankie",
    count: 3
  }
],
imagesArr: [],
}

function gameObjectArrayBuilder(obj) {
  var resultArr = obj.flatMap( f=> {
 return [...Array(f.count).fill(f.image)]
});
  
  return resultArr;

}

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObjectArrayBuilder(gameObj.objects);


//View result
var html = document.querySelector("#content");
html.innerHTML = gameObj.imagesArr;
console.log(gameObj.imagesArr)

//Result should be
//[bat, bat, bat, bat, bat, spider, spider, spider, spider, frankie, frankie, frankie]
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need `.map(...).flatMap`, just `.flatMap(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `for` cycle to add items to a tmp array, then return it:

```js
//game object state
var gameObj = {
objects: [
  {
    image: "bat",
    count: 5
  },
  {
    image: "spider",
    count: 4
  },
  {
    image: "frankie",
    count: 3
  }
],
imagesArr: [],
}

function gameObjectArrayBuilder(obj)
{
  var resultArr = [];
  resultArr = obj.map(buildArr);

  function buildArr(prop)
  {
    var image = prop.image;
    var count = prop.count;
    
    // USE A TMP ARRAY
    let tmpArr = []
    for (let j=0; j<count; j++) {
      tmpArr.push(prop.image);
    }
    
    return tmpArr
  }
  
  return resultArr;
}

gameObj.imagesArr = gameObjectArrayBuilder(gameObj.objects);


//View result
var html = document.querySelector("#content");
html.innerHTML = gameObj.imagesArr;
```

```html
<div id="content">

</div>
```